# How can I get the output of a command terminated by a alarm() call in Perl?

Tags: perl, windows-services

#### Case 1

If I run below command i.e `iperf` in UL only, then I am able to capture the output in txt file

```
@output = readpipe("iperf.exe -u -c 127.0.0.1 -p 5001 -b 3600k -t 10 -i 1");
open FILE, ">Misplay_DL.txt" or die $!;
print FILE @output;
close FILE;
```

#### Case 2

When I run `iperf` in DL mode , as we know server will start listening in cont. mode like below even after getting data from client (Here i am using server and client on LAN)

```
@output = system("iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001 -i 1");
```

On server side:

```
D:\_IOT_SESSION_RELATED\SEEM_ELEMESNTS_AT_COMM_PORT_CONF\Tput_Related_Tools\AUTO
MATION_APP_\AUTOMATION_UTILITY>iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size: 8.00 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[1896] local 192.168.5.101 port 5001 connected with 192.168.5.101 port 4878
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth Jitter Lost/Total Datagrams
[1896] 0.0- 2.0 sec 881 KBytes 3.58 Mbits/sec 0.000 ms 0/ 614 (0%)
```

Command prompt does not appear, process is contd...

On client side:

```
D:\_IOT_SESSION_RELATED\SEEM_ELEMESNTS_AT_COMM_PORT_CONF\Tput_Related_Tools\AUTO
MATION_APP_\AUTOMATION_UTILITY>iperf.exe -u -c 192.168.5.101 -p 5001 -b 3600k -t
2 -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.5.101, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size: 8.00 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[1880] local 192.168.5.101 port 4878 connected with 192.168.5.101 port 5001
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth
[1880] 0.0- 1.0 sec 441 KBytes 3.61 Mbits/sec
[1880] 1.0- 2.0 sec 439 KBytes 3.60 Mbits/sec
[1880] 0.0- 2.0 sec 881 KBytes 3.58 Mbits/sec
[1880] Server Report:
[1880] 0.0- 2.0 sec 881 KBytes 3.58 Mbits/sec 0.000 ms 0/ 614 (0%)
[1880] Sent 614 datagrams

D:\_IOT_SESSION_RELATED\SEEM_ELEMESNTS_AT_COMM_PORT_CONF\Tput_Related_Tools\AUTO
MATION_APP_\AUTOMATION_UTILITY>
```

So with this as server is cont. listening and never terminates so can't take output of server side to a txt file as it is going to the next command itself to create a txt file.

So I adopted the `alarm()` function to terminate the server side (`iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001`) commands after it received all data from the client.

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
my $command = "iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001";
my @output;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" };
    alarm 20;
    #@output = `$command`;
#my @output = readpipe("iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001");
#my @output = exec("iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001");

my @output = system("iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001");
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    warn "$command timed out.\n";
} else {
    print "$command successful. Output was:\n", @output;
}
open FILE, ">display.txt" or die $!;
print FILE @output_1;
close FILE;
```

I know that with system command I cannot capture the o/p to a txt file. I tried with `readpipe()` and `exec()` calls but these were also in vain.

Could someone please take a look and let me know why the `iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001` is not terminating even after the alarm call and to take the output to a txt file?

---

mobrule-- Finally I am able to achieve what I wanted. Below is the code I used, but now it is also giving me an error on each subsequent run...

Error message:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001 successful. Output was:
```

Code:

```
my @command_output;
eval { 
    my $file = "abc6.txt";    
    $command = "iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001";
    alarm 10;
    system("$command > $file");
    alarm 0;
close $file;
};
if ($@) {
    warn "$command timed out.\n";
} else {
   print "$command successful. Output was:\n", $file;
}
unlink $file;
```

Output:

```
abc6.txt
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size: 8.00 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[1892] local 192.168.5.101 port 5001 connected with 192.168.5.101 port 3553
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[1892]  0.0- 2.0 sec   881 KBytes  3.61 Mbits/sec  0.000 ms    0/  614 (0%)
```

Also, when for each run of this "iperf.exe" the process always remains live in Taskmanager,
if I kill it manually before each run or change the file for taking output every time, then I am able to run it successfully one after another.

Could you please suggest how I can kill that process (rather than doing it manually from task manager) and get rid of that problem?

I tried to unlink the file used but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: @rockyurock Please make an effort to format your post properly.

Comment: Without commenting on any other part of your code, note that `system` does not return the output of the command. You need to use backticks for that. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: You should print out the $@ to see your error is the alarm or if its something else in your eval, also your using @output and @output_1, if you used strict you'd get a compile error.

Comment: Hello Tim, 

one simple doubt, how can i perform some command operation and to take its o/p to a txt file within a timed value using alram() call ?

/rocky

Comment: I am trying to automate this iperf very badly. Can you share the script?

Answer (score 1):

Since the command might time out, you'll want to save as much output as you can while the command is running. Two ways to do this are:

1. Save the output to a file and read the file contents after the command finishes or times out:

   ```
   my @command_output;
   eval { 
       $SIG{ALRM} = { die "timeout\n" };
       alarm(30);
       system("$command > $file");
       alarm(0);
   };
   open my $fh, '<', $file;  # error handling omitted for brevity
   @command_output = <$fh>;
   close $fh;     # oops, this said "close $file" before ... not a big deal.
   ```
2. Run the command with `open` in `-|` mode and save as much output as you can while the command is running:

   ```
   my @command_output = ();
   eval {
       $SIG{ALRM} = { ... };
       alarm(30);
       open my $process, "$command |"; # or open my $process, '-|', $command
       while (<$process>) {
           push @command_output, $_;
       }
       close $process;
       alarm(0);
   };
   ```

---

In for a penny, in for a pound.

After figuring out what `iperf.exe` was and downloading it, I got this script to "work":

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $command = "C:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/iperf.exe -u -s -p 25005";
my $file = "abc6.txt";
my ($pid,@command_output);
eval {
    my $process;
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { 
      kill 'INT', $pid;
      close $process;
      die "timeout\n" 
    };
    alarm(10);
    $pid = open $process, "$command |";
    while (<$process>) {
      push @command_output, $_;
    }
    close $process;
    alarm(0);
};
print "eval block result was: $@\n";
print "Output was:\n------\n",@command_output;
```

I strongly urge you to familiarize yourself with all of the functions and syntax of this code before you try to get too much use out of it.

Comment: i tried, but either way did not work at all

Ist way::

my @command_output;
eval { 
 $file = "dummy.txt";    
 $command = "iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001";
    $SIG{ALRM} = { die "timeout\n" };
    alarm 30;
    system("$command > $file");
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
 #print"$@\n"; 
 warn "$command timed out.\n";
} else {
   print "$command successful. Output was:\n", @output;
}

open my $fh, '<', $file;  # error handling omitted for brevity
@command_output = <$fh>;
print $fh @command_output;
close $file;

i got o/p => iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001 timed out.

Comment: second way::no o/p at all
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
my $command = readpipe("iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001");
my @output;eval {local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" };
    alarm 10; #my @output = `iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001`;
    #my @output = readpipe("iperf.exe -u -c 192.168.5.101 -p 5001 -b 3600k -t 5");
open my $process, "$command |"; # or open my $process, '-|', $command
    while (<$process>) {push @output, $_;}alarm 0;
open FILE, ">display.txt" or die $!;
print FILE @output;
close FILE;
};if ($@) {#print"$@\n";warn "$command timed out.\n";} else {print "$command successful. Output was:\n", @output;}

Comment: @rockyurock: are you using both `@command_output` and `@output`? You should use one or the other but not both. I omitted `use strict; use warnings;` from my examples for brevity, but maybe I should put them in.

Comment: @rockyurock Re 1st comment: Don't say `print $fh @command_output`. `$fh` is an input filehandle. If you want to print to your screen just say `print @command_output`

Comment: @rockyurock Re 2nd comment: It looks you are writing to the file `display.txt` inside the `eval` block? If the command times out you will exit from the block and that code won't get executed. Move it outside the `eval` block.

Comment: @rockyurock Re 2nd comment: I expect `$command` to contain `"iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001"`. By making it the return value of `readpipe`, you are setting `$command` to the **output** of `"iperf.exe ..."`! (In which case, you can just `print $command`).

Comment: How can you say that it is working ??

i tried your porgram as such on windows and the cursor is always blinking and did not get any output generated.

however when i replaced the command my $command = "iperf.exe -u -s -p 25005";

with system(); linke my $command = "system(iperf.exe -u -s -p 25005");

i could see the output on terminal but again the process never terminated and no o/p generated at all

/rocky...

Comment: @rockyurock Please read up on Perl's `system` function (see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#system_LIST__ , for example). The return value is **not** the output of the command. When you call `system` outside the `eval` block, the command is running and is not subject to the alarm.